# Python Using Multiple Cores Without Me Asking

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am running a double nested loop over `i,j` and I use sklearn's PCA function inside the inner loop. Though I am not using any parallel processing packages, the task manager is telling me that all my CPU's are running between 80%-100%. I am pleasantly surprised by this, and have 2 questions:

1) What is going on here? How did python decide to use multiple CPU's? How is it breaking up the loop? Printing out the `i,j` values, they are still being completed in order.

2) Would the code be sped even more up by explicitly parallelizing it with a package, or will the difference be negligible?

Comment: `sklearn` uses many parallelized algorithms, so does numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Several scikit-learn tools... rely internally on Python’s multiprocessing module to parallelize execution onto several Python processes by passing n_jobs > 1 as argument."](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-sometime-get-a-crash-freeze-with-n-jobs-1-under-osx-or-linux)

One explanation, therefore, is that somewhere in your code `n_jobs` is a valid argument for an sklearn process. I'm a bit confused though, because only the specialized PCA tools have that argument in the docs.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html (No `n_jobs`)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html (Has `n_jobs`)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA.html (Has `n_jobs`)

Numpy may also be the culprit, but you would have to dig into the implementation a bit to begin examining where `sklearn` is making use of `numpy` parallel tools.

Sklearn has a landing page specifically for optimizing existing `sklearn` tools (and writing your own tools.) They offer a variety of suggestions and specifically mention `joblib`.
[Check it out](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html#multi-core-parallelism-using-joblib-parallel)

Comment: So does that mean that each iteration is being parallelized, rather than different CPU's covering different iterations? For my case, that seems inefficient.

Comment: If you want to restrict the iterations to n jobs, then you can use a Pool from joblib or multiprocessing libraries, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. It seems better to have each iteration of `i,j` attacked by a separate CPU. Right?

Comment: No, I don't actually see the benefit of doing that, because in a vanilla for-loop in python the next iteration will not begin until you finish all the ones that precede it. If you are using an async for-loop then you need to analyze the real performance of difference strategies

Comment: True. I was assuming each iteration would be non-sequential in a parallelized loop.